# Isochrones using OSMnx

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap, geopandas, qgis, osmnx

I am quite new to geospatial data. In my work, I have to calculate the polygon using isochrones. The Data on which I am working is quite large(1.2 million rows). To execute each row, it takes around 1 sec, so by that calculation, it will take around 13days to run this code!. Is there any way to reduce the time?

```
def get_isochrone(lon, lat, count, walk_time=10, speed=4.5):   
    loc = (lat, lon)
    G = ox.graph_from_point(loc, simplify=True, network_type='walk')
    #Create nodes geodataframe from Graph network (G)
    gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
    x, y = gdf_nodes['geometry'].unary_union.centroid.xy
    # center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
    center_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (y[0], x[0]))
    meters_per_minute = speed * 1000 / 60
    for u, v, k, data in G.edges(data=True, keys=True):
        data['time'] = data['length'] / meters_per_minute
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=walk_time, distance='time')
    node_points = [Point(data['x'], data['y']) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
    polys = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    if (count%5)==0:
        print(count)
    return polys

wsp_df['polygon'] = wsp_df.apply(lambda x: get_isochrone(x.lon, x.lat, x.counter ), axis=1)
```

Comment: Have you profiled and timed your code? What specific lines are slow? Do you need to create the graph every time instead of reusing (and possibly subgraphing) one larger graph across your whole study site? At a minimum you could vectorize your use of `ox.distance.nearest_nodes` outside of a loop to solve all the nearest nodes at once.

Comment: Yes, the code is downloading the graph each time. As I am running this code for whole Germany, I tried to load the graph but after waiting for 2-3hrs the process will be killed.